# A* Implementation in C, Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For a school project in C, I want to create a pathfinding algorithm, I decided to use A*.
After long reflexion and rewrite of many time all the code I can't find what is wrong. It must be because of the memory management but I can't figure out where it goes wrong. Even after looking for hours on forums I didn't find anything interesting.

The gdb help me a little bit more when he shows me in which function the segfault occurs.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000008000917 in list_prepend ()
#1  0x0000000008000b38 in findPath ()
#2  0x0000000008001473 in main ()
```

I use struct to represent my Nodes and for my lists of pointers to the Nodes.

```
typedef struct Coord Coord;
struct Coord{
  int x;
  int y;
};

typedef struct Node{
    bool walkable;
    bool wayToGo;
    Coord pos;
    int gCost;
    int hCost;
    int fCost; // fCost = gCost + hCost
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

typedef struct NodeList{
    Node * pNode;
    struct NodeList * next;
    struct NodeList * previous;
} NodeList;
```

And the function that raise the SIGSEGV :

```
NodeList * list_prepend(NodeList *old, Node *pNode)
{

    NodeList *list = list_create(pNode); 
    if (list){                     
       list->next = old;             
       old->previous = list;
    }
    return list;                    
}
```

Where :

```
NodeList * list_create (Node *pNode)
{
    NodeList *list = malloc(sizeof(NodeList));
    if (list)
    {
        list->pNode = pNode;
        list->next = NULL;
        list->previous = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```

I think that the problem comes from `old->previous = list` because it looks like `old->previous` gives NULL and I try to affect something to NULL. I don't know and that's why I'm asking.

If you have any idea or if you can share a good debugging technique that would be great.

If needed here is the full code I wrote to test the pathfinder :
[pathFinding.c](https://github.com/ApocalHyps/Pacman/blob/master/pathFinding.c)

Comment: in the code you've shared, the one mystery dereference is indeed `old->previous`. If that hasn't been initialized to point to valid memory, then `old->` invokes undefined behavior. What do you do with `old` before passing it to `list_prepend`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NodeList * list_prepend(NodeList *old, Node *pNode)
{

    NodeList *list = list_create(pNode);
    if (list){
       list->next = old;
       (*old).previous = list; // Since this accesses *old, old cannot be NULL
    }
    return list;
}
```

See the comment above. It is a pre-condition of calling `list_prepend` that `old` not be `NULL`.

```
NodeList * getNeighbours(Node grid[row][column], Node * pNode)
{
        int x, y;
        NodeList * list = NULL;
        for(x = -1; x <= 1; x++){
                for(y = -1; y <= 1; y++){
                        if(x == y || x == -y)
                                continue;

                        int checkX = pNode->pos.x + x;
                        int checkY = pNode->pos.y + y;
                        if (checkX >= 0 && checkX < column && checkY >= 0 && checkY < row){
                                list = list_prepend(list, &(grid[checkY][checkX])); // Uh oh, list is NULL on first invocation
                        }
                }           
        }
        return list;
}
```

See the comment. The first call to `list_prepend` violates the pre-condition. It is very important to clearly document (in comments) the pre-conditions of your functions. It is also extremely helpful to test that all pre-conditions are true and report any that aren't. It makes debugging much easier.

I'm also puzzled by your thinking in a few places. For example:

```
NodeList * list_append(NodeList *list, Node *pNode)
{/*Rajouter le previous*/
    NodeList **plist = &list;
    while (*plist)
       plist = &(*plist)->next;
    *plist = list_create(pNode);
    if (*plist)
       return list;
    else
       return NULL;
}
```

Why the mess with double indirection in `plist`? And why don't you set the newly-created node's `prev`? Why not just:

```
NodeList * list_append(NodeList *list, Node *pNode)
{
    if (list == NULL)
        return list_create(pNode);
    NodeList *plist = list;
    while (plist->next != NULL)
       plist = plist->next;
    plist->next = list_create(pNode);
    if (plist->next == NULL)
        return NULL;
    plist->next->prev = plist;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I use the type of list found online at https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structures_de_donn%C3%A9es_en_C/Les_listes_simples I've just change it a little bit to add a pointer to the previous element in the list. I don't use the fact list_append it doesn't work don't look at it I going to delete it because I don't use it.

Comment: @jeanalpha2401 No, you don't. That is a singly-linked list (no `prev` or `previous` pointer) and you are using a doubly-linked list (each node has a pointer to its previous node).

Comment: ok, I get rid of it. But now how can I do? I want it to be NULL by default but I want to change it in this function. How can I affect it to a new value without accessing it? Is there another way I don't see?

Comment: Just write the code that does what you want. In the case of `list_prepend` you probably want to eliminate the pre-condition by testing if `old` is `NULL` and handling that case correctly. `if (old) old->previous = list;`.

Comment: Your attempt to "change" a singly-linked list to a doubly linked list is inadvisable. The two data structures are different enough that it's much easier to just code a properly doubly-linked list from scratch. It's too easy to get it wrong (as you did) and miss cases.

Comment: I just started a month ago programming in C, before I used to code in python I didn't know about that doubly-linked list thing and where to find it. Thank you for your help.